# Invalid Syntax class Template(metaclass=_TemplateMetaclass) with mod_wsgi, apache and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, apache, sqlalchemy, mod-wsgi, bottle

[image]I have a script where I import:

```
from bottle import route, request
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET 

@route('/getmember')
def get_member():
    pass
run(host='localhost', port=8080, reloader=True)
```

I can run this script successfully using the bottle build in web server: `$python3.2 getmember.py`

That done I want to run the app using Apache and `mod_wsgi` and I create a script called `adapter.wsgi`:

```
import sys, os, bottle
sys.path = ['/var/www/getmember/'] + sys.path
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
import getmember
application = bottle.default_app()
```

In Apache I have:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess getmember user=www-data group=www-data processes=1 threads=5 python-path=/usr/lib/python3.2/site-packages
WSGIScriptAlias /getmember /var/www/idcheck/adapter.wsgi
<Directory /var/www/getmember>
    WSGIProcessGroup getmember
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

When I run this script using the browser on: `localhost/getmember`, I get a HTTP 200 Error and Apache Error log shows:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=10271): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/getmember/adapter.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/getmember/adapter.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
    import getmember # This loads your application
  File "/var/www/getmember/getmember.py", line 10, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .sql import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/sql/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .expression import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/sql/expression.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .. import util, exc, inspection
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/util/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .compat import callable, cmp, reduce, defaultdict, py25_dict, \\
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 100, in <module>
    from urllib.parse import parse_qsl
    ImportError: No module named parse
```

So why is it working under normal python call (meaning all libraries and packages are okay) yet under wsgi & Apache it throws this error? I get a feeling it cannot find the requried path to that package but am not sure how to add it.

**EDIT**

I ran the `import sys` and `print sys.path` to get all the paths that are loaded when I run the python3.2 environment. I got multiple paths which I added to Python-path in Apache:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess idcheck user=www-data group=www-data processes=1 threads=5 python-path=/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py3.2.egg:/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/logilab_common-0.58.3-py3.2.egg:/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/logilab_astng-0.24.1-py3.2.egg:/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg:/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/psycopg2-2.4.6-py3.2-linux-x86_64.egg:/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-1.2.1-py3.2.egg:/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sqlautocode-0.6b1-py3.2.egg:/usr/lib/python3.2:/usr/lib/python3.2/plat-linux2:/usr/lib/python3.2/lib-dynload:/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

With that, the earlier error disappeared and I got this new one of invalid syntax. Is there something broken with SQLAlchemy and mod_wsgi + Apache?

```
mod_wsgi (pid=21339): Target WSGI script '/var/www/getmember/adapter.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=21339): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/getmember/adapter.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/getmember/adapter.wsgi", line 6, in <module>
    import getmember # This loads your application
  File "/var/www/getmember/getmember.py", line 10, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import inspect as _inspect
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/inspect.py", line 36, in <module>
    import string
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/string.py", line 89
    class Template(metaclass=_TemplateMetaclass):
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Apache is using a version 2 Python executable? You could check the search path of apache user or look at the WSGI directives WSGIPythonHome / WSGIPythonExecutable.

Try:

```
import sys
```

-snip-

```
@route('/test', method='GET')
def test():
    return sys.version
```

Or:

```
#grep Python /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

Comment: I think its using Python3.2 because I have this entry in apache2.conf: `WSGIDaemonProcess idcheck user=www-data group=www-data processes=1 threads=5 python-path=/usr/lib/python3.2/site-packages`? also, before I inserted that line, it could not find the `bottle` package. Now it does but it now fails at the SQLAlchemy section